# Can Content and DataContext work through Binding at the same time?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am working on loading the Views and ViewModel at the run time in my MainView.xaml page using class properties in (MainViewModel.cs).

I do not have Direct reference to the project which has my View and ViewModel (BaseModuleView,BaseModuleViewModel)

I have got this View and ViewModel from Resource dictonary and loaded them in my Class properties

If i Bind only `Content` the the View loads up but I am Binding Both View and ViewModel with Binding then the page shows nothing.

Here is my code

This is my Main View

```xml
<UserControl 
    x:Class="namespace.MainView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:namespace"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
    mc:Ignorable="d" \>

    <TabControl 
        TabStripPlacement="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        SelectedIndex="0"\>

        <TabItem 
            Header="Base" 
            Content="{Binding BaseModuleView}" 
            DataContext="{Binding BaseModuleViewModel}" />

    </TabControl\>
</UserControl\>
```

- I tried to Bind only the View (`Content="{Binding BaseView}"`) then it works
- I tried to Bind only the ViewModel (`DataContext="{Binding BaseViewModel}"`) it works

but it does not work if use Binding for both `Contet` and `DataContext`.

It would be helpful, if you have any idea or suggestion for me to try

Comment: Take a look at this sample https://github.com/AndyONeill/WPF_NavigationViewModelFirst

Comment: Thanks Andy. Your solution is simple and effective. But in my case I do NOT have a direct reference to the project which has my View and ViewModel. I loaded them to my Class property. I am looking for the way to load them in my MainView.xaml without having a direct reference to the project.

Comment: Put the association of  view to viewmodel in this resource dictionary. Use mef or reflection  to discover the viewmodel(s)

Comment: Yes loaded my View and ViewModel into the resourceDictionary.
then get them into my Class Properties (mainViewModel). Thanks for your valuable input

Answer (score -1):

I figured the answer to my question. I am posting it here if anyone find it helpfull

1. We can bind the DataContext to the View Property in the class itself.
2. then load that View property which already bind with respective ViewModel in the MainView.xaml file

My class property in MainViewModel.cs

```
public UserControl BaseModuleView { get; private set; }
```

Load View and ViewModel to your properties like below

```
this.BaseModuleView = (UserControl)mybaseModuleView;
this.BaseModuleView.DataContext = myBaseModuleViewModel;
```

MainView.xaml look like this

```
<TabControl>
<TabItem x:Name="BaseTabItem" Header="Base" Content="{Binding BaseModuleView}" />
</TabControl>
```

Comment: View models must not contain view elements. There should be a set of DataTemplates that create views for different types of view models. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).